# branch.io universal linking custom https uri

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links

Is it possible to get branch.io to try to open the iOS app with a specific HTTPS URI such as `https://example.com/openapp`?

I can only set up iOS URI Scheme which the app does not have and will not have.

Also is it possible to pass query params through branch.io?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to open an app with a specific URI scheme, the said app should be configured/ modified to handle the URI scheme. If it doesn’t support the particular URI scheme you will not be able to open the app.

You can pass information to your app along with Branch links by appending query parameters. You can also create Branch links dynamically by appending the query parameters to your Branch link sub-domain.

Here are the formats you can use based on the link subdomain:

[image: Dynamic links]

Comment: I want branch.io to open the app through universal links. Our app targets ios 10+. URI schemes are dead, see https://blog.branch.io/uri-schemes-and-universal-links-for-ios/

Comment: I you wish to open the app via Universal links, you will need to set that up on the Branch dashboard and your App. Here is the complete guide for it.
https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/#configure-branch

Comment: So isn't it necessary to have URI schemes set up in order to use branch.io?

Comment: @adam Post iOS9, Apple disabled the use of URI schemes for redirecting to the App from Safari. Hence, you should setup your App to handle deeplinking via Universal Links.

However, there are still apps which support redirection using URI schemes e.g Chrome browser, Gmail, Mozilla browser etc. So if a user clicks on a Branch link on any these apps (on iOS), URI schemes will be used to redirect to your app.

Branch will redirect to your App using the appropriate method depending on the browser, OS. Hence, you should setup support for both Universal links and URI schemes.

Comment: >> Apple disabled the use of URI schemes for redirecting to the App from Safari
This is not true. custom URL schemes still works. It just you can't detect if App installed or not post-iOS9.

Comment: @AmrutaDeshmukh i have a link like this `link.mydomain.com/asdf?key=123` and when opened in the browser it gets redirected to `mydomain.com` without the path and query strings. But our feature has a web implementation so we need the path and params. Any guesses?

Comment: @AmrutaDeshmukh in addition to my prev comment: a better example would be an `/activation?key=123` or `/activation/123` which is implemented on the web and mobile also. Web should be a fallback.

Comment: @adam could you please write into `integrations@branch.io` with a detailed explanation of your use case.